# How do I merge a branch to origin/master

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

Given the state of my repo below. Let's say I'm not ready to push my changes in my master branch but I am ready to push my changes in my dev branch to origin/master. How do I perform this ?

```
* dcf6713 (master) added line 2 to file2.txt
| * ceee7ec (HEAD -> dev) added line 3 to file1.txt
|/  
* c79818c (origin/master) added line 2 to file1.txt
* 4b11fc7 init
```

Comment: curious to know why you would want to push your dev upstream to master while bypassing your local master

Comment: If I'm not ready to push upstream the changes I made in my local master but I'm ready to push my changes in dev. I guess the take away here is you would never want to directly work in master branch but I imagine it could still happen if there is something in your local master you don't wish to push upstream anymore.

Comment: While it is not best practice for work-flow, I could see it happening. My answer below should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

from man git-push:

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```

Push the current branch to the remote ref matching master in the origin
repository. This form is convenient to push the current branch without
thinking about its local name.